# Bash While loop Not Ending

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I was playing with bash programming. I have written a simple bash program which takes input from reader. If reader typed the string "bye" the while loop ends. So the program is pretty simple I have written something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
inputString="hello"
while [ inputString != "bye" ]
do
    echo "Please write something (bye to quit)"
    read inputString
    echo "You typed : ${inputString}"
done
```

It works perfectly until user type two words at a time.

If user type something like this

```
bye bye
```

Program crashes giving the following error

```
./WhileLoop.sh: 5: [: bye: unexpected operator
```

How can i modify the code so that program can take multiple input?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put double quotes around `inputString` in `while`'s condition. Without double quotes, if your variable is empty, it will raise a error.

Update:

There's a typo on script, add `$` before `inputString`, make variable substitution: `while [ "$inputString" != "bye" ]`

Comment: That's the correct answer. All I need is to put $inputString into double quotes

Comment: @sadasidha No, this ISN'T the correct answer. The quoted `"inputString"` isn't the same as the quoted `"$inputString"`. So, yes, need to quote, but need to put the `$` in the front. Please, MARK only really correct answers.

Comment: @jm666 I assume the lack of a `$` is a typo in the question, because the posted code would not produce the given error. (It would simply loop forever because the two literal strings would never equal each other.)

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` 4+ you can also:

```
while read -r -p 'Please write something (bye to quit)>' ans
do
   echo "your answer =$ans="
   #convert the $ans to lowercase to match "BYE"
   #use matching to match "bye bye" or "byeanythinghere"
   #in case of double [[ don't needed the "", but never harm, so using it
   [[ "${ans,,}" =~ bye.* ]] && exit 0
   #[[ ${ans,,} =~ bye.* ]] && exit 0   #works too
   echo "not bye - yet"
done
```

Comment: FYI, the `,,` operator requires `bash` 4.

Comment: @chepner never remember what knows old and new... i have 4.3 ;) edited.

Comment: It helps when Mac OS X stays stuck on 3.2 :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a $ in front of a variable to have it expanded.  $inputString

Comment: No it's not working the problem still exist if I write while loop like this
while [ $inputString != "bye" ]